# HttpUnhandledException on Form_Init, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, runtime-error

This error generated from `Global.asax` shows on one of my webforms on the published server on `ASP.NET`.

```
9/8/2015 7:33:09 AM ex.ToString: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PCMSYS.NET4.rpt_CAPA_By_Client.rpt_CAPA_By_Client_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PCMSYS.NET4\rpt_CAPA_By_Client.aspx.vb:line 34
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.rpt_capa_by_client_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

9/8/2015 7:33:09 AM ex.Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

9/8/2015 7:33:09 AM ex.Inner.ToString: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at PCMSYS.NET4.rpt_CAPA_By_Client.rpt_CAPA_By_Client_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\PCMSYS.NET4\rpt_CAPA_By_Client.aspx.vb:line 34
   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

9/8/2015 7:33:09 AM ex.Inner.Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Browsing it with Visual Studio doesn't produce this kind of error.

The error on ***`rpt_CAPA_By_Client.aspx.vb:line 34`*** points to the first code on my `Form_Init` which is `txtAuditDateFrom`:

```
txtAuditDateFrom.Text = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, 1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
txtAuditDateTo.Text = Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
LoadClients()
```

HTML Design

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="rpt_CAPA_By_Client.aspx.vb" Inherits="PCMSYS.NET4.rpt_CAPA_By_Client" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>CAPA By Client</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .b { font-weight: bold } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div>
            <span class="b">SELECT OPTIONS:</span><br />
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="border: 1px solid black">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="b">Received Date</span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="24px" Width="80px" ID="txtAuditDateFrom"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender Animated="false" runat="server" PopupButtonID="Button1" ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txtAuditDateFrom"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="..." Height="28px" Width="28px" />

                                </td>
                                <td><span class="b">To</span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Height="24px" Width="80px" ID="txtAuditDateTo"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                                    <asp:CalendarExtender Animated="false" runat="server" PopupButtonID="Button2" ID="CalendarExtender2" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" TargetControlID="txtAuditDateTo"></asp:CalendarExtender>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="..." Height="28px" Width="28px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="b">Client</span></td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropdownList1" Height="32px" Width="224px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button3" Text="Apply" Height="28px" Width="76px" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button4" Text="Default" Height="28px" Width="76px" />
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Size="X-Small" Font-Names="Verdana">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">All CAPA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2" Selected="True">Open CA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Closed CA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Open PA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Closed PA</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" Height="50px" Width="350px" ToolPanelView="None" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm Source

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class rpt_CAPA_By_Client
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim rpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim strConnection As String = "********"
    Dim strCAPAStatus = ""

    Private Sub LoadClients()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet


        con.Open()

        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usrView_Clients", con)
        adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adp.Fill(ds)

        For a As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            DropdownList1.Items.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(a).Item("Clients").ToString)
        Next

        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub rpt_CAPA_By_Client_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        txtAuditDateFrom.Text = New Date(Now.Year, Now.Month, 1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ' Error points here
        txtAuditDateTo.Text = Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

        LoadClients()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Select Case RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value
            Case 2
                strCAPAStatus = " AND (Status='Open' OR Status IS NULL)"
            Case 3
                strCAPAStatus = " AND Status='Closed'"
            Case 4
                strCAPAStatus = " AND Expr1 = 'Closed'"
            Case 5
                strCAPAStatus = " AND (Expr1 = 'Open' OR Expr1 IS NULL)"
            Case Else
                strCAPAStatus = ""
        End Select

        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usrTbl_CAPA_By_Client WHERE auditdate >= '" & txtAuditDateFrom.Text & " 00:00:00' AND auditdate <= '" & txtAuditDateTo.Text & " 23:59:59' " & strCAPAStatus & IIf(Trim(DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Value) = "", "", " AND ClientCode='" & DropdownList1.SelectedItem.Value & "'"), con)
        adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adp.Fill(ds, "usrTbl_CAPA_By_Client")

        rpt = New ReportDocument
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/rptCAPAByClient.rpt"))

        rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub rpt_CAPA_By_Client_Unload(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
        On Error Resume Next

        rpt.Close()
        rpt.Dispose()

        If rpt IsNot Nothing Then Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rpt)
        rpt = Nothing

        GC.Collect()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I added detailed source code like what @TallTed suggested.

Comment: We don't need that much of the error output ... but much more of the source code which generates the error is needed if we're to debug it at all.

Comment: The error points from the textbox from Form.Init like what I said on my statement so why would you ask for the detailed source code. Anyways, I already added it, hoping it would be solved.

Comment: @TallTed, are you there?